# компиляция Python под MIPS процессор на Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, mips

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь установить Kaltura Client на платформу OpenWRT с процессором MIPS 400 Mhz, 32 MB RAM, 16 MB Flash.

Столкнулся с проблемой, при установки клиента, он запускает компиляцию Python´а(2.7.2) под процессор MIPS, но из за низкой мощности OpenWRT рушит весь процесс. Пытаюсь установить компилятор Python - ELDK, под Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. При установке, ISO образом, консоль выдает мне следующие ошибки

```
 sudo sh install.sh mips
-e *** Installing ./targets/mips/eldk-eglibc-i686-mips-toolchain-gmae-5.5.3.sh
    into /opt/eldk-5.5.3/mips
readlink: invalid option -- ' '
Try 'readlink --help' for more information.
./targets/mips/eldk-eglibc-i686-mips-toolchain-gmae-5.5.3.sh: 104: [: -o: unexpected operator
tar: option requires an argument -- 'C'
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
ls: cannot access /environment-setup-*: No such file or directory
/relocate_sdk.sh: line 2: /relocate_sdk.py: No such file or directory
```

Есть у кого предположения чего не хватает, или какой-либо другой метод компилирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае у вас проблемы с программой `readlink`, которая имеет на вашей платформе другие опции чем ожидается в скрипте `install.sh`.

Что вы можете сделать?

**Во-первых,** запускайте срипт в режиме трассировки,
для того чтобы видеть где очередная ошибка.

```
sudo sh -x instal.sh mips
```

**Во-вторых,** когда ошибка возникает, выясняйте почему она возникла,
чаще всего это просто вопрос совместимости, требуются другие опции или порядок аргументов и так далее.

**В-третьих,** когда вы видите в чём ошибка, правьте `install.sh`, чтобы он работал в данном случае правильно, и продвигайтесь на один шаг вперёд.

Если встречаются ошибки, которые вы не можете обойти, делитись ими с нами, мы будем их обходить вместе.

Comment: попробовал установить на Debian ELDK. Работает лучше, но также показывает мне одну проблему. Не могли бы вы помочь? Запускаю все в su http://pastebin.com/GiiPp2Sx

Comment: Он пытается прочитать три файла как будто это было бы имя одного файла. Конечно же такого имени нет. Запустите опять с -x, посмотрим, откуда такое берётся

Comment: http://pastebin.com/M9u2qL2B

Comment: Что у вас в скрипте в этом месте: `tarball=`?

Comment: извините за долгий ответ... К сожалению были проблемы.
http://pastebin.com/Rx4kERth вот что в `tarball=`

Comment: @Insider: У вас получается несколько файлов подпадают под этот шаблон. Сделайте `echo ${SRC_DIR}/targets/${target}/core-image-${img}*-${MACHINE}.tar*` для проверки

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zAYJVxDn вот как-то так

Comment: @Insider: что это? Вы можете просто вызвать ту команду, которую я показал?

Comment: извините, не правильно вас понял. Вот что выдает `root@ubuntu:~/Downloads/eldk-download$ echo ${SRC_DIR}/targets/${target}/core-image-${img}*-${MACHINE}.tar*
/targets//core-image-*-.tar*`